# Php regex, match pattern?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to make a regex that will match this pattern,

Must be 40 characters long,

Must contain only letters and numbers,

Must contain no spaces,

Case insensitive,

So far I have come up with this but it does not work;

```
/^[0-9a-f]+$/i
```

Thanks

Comment: Ahh ok thanks that is where I was going wrong, thanks

Comment: The `a-f` bit is odd. You don't want to match on G through Z? Are you trying to match hexadecimal digits? If so, note that the maximum value of a hexadecimal digit is e (decimal 15), not f (decimal 16 is 10 in hex).

Comment: @GarrettAlbright: Actually, f is 15. ;)

Comment: …Oh. Now that I count on my third hand, I see you're right. Well, that's embarrassing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/^[0-9a-f]{40}$/i
```

should do the trick. The number in curly brackets defines the number of characters.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
/^[\da-z]{40}$/i
```

If you really only want the letters a-f then use:

```
/^[\da-f]{40}$/i
```

Comment: `\w` should also match underscores (`_`), which I do not think is something the OP is after.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:`/^[0-9a-z]{40,40}$/i`

Comment: `{40,40}` can be replaced by `{40}`.

Comment: A Single number between curly braces denotes an exact number which must be matched :).